# What is the equivalent of a 20 minutes hiit session in minutes of cardio?

Tags: cardio, hiit

How many minutes of cardio do you think I need to replace a 20 minutes hiit traditional session on a certain day that I suddenly want?

(And I mean with the cardio of skipping rope at 70-85% of my max heartrate)

Comment: How many apples do I need to eat to replace the oranges I stopped eating? Kidding aside, why are you making the switch, and *what are you trying to keep equivalent*?

Comment: They train different things; as-is it's difficult to answer.

Comment: What are your goals?

Comment: Can you give more detail as to what you're actually replacing? How many minutes of what kind of HIIT, for example? This question is currently rather vague.

Comment: The hiit is also with skipping rope reaching 90% of my max heartrate in each interval of work for enough time, and the rest periods are until my bpm lowers to 70% of my heartrate which in total produces 8-12 total intervals in 20 minutes more or less + 3 minutes of warming up and 5 of stretching which aren't counted in the 20 minutes session

Comment: the goals are to substitute some days hiit for cardio or cardio for hiit if I want

Comment: Because pure hiit or pure cardio all the week except saturday and sunday (strength training) seems boring to me.

Comment: Which am I replacing? cardio for hiit or etc, what type of equivalence? At least equivalence in weight loss or calories or amount of exercise.

Answer (score 1):

You can't effectively replace one or the other on a certain day suddenly because you feel like it. HIIT works different metabolic pathways than general cardio. You should have chosen one or the other depending on your fitness goals, and to replace one randomly because you feel like it means you're not following your training program.

If you decide to skip your HIIT training one day, you can do cardio in its place, but there isn't a certain number of minutes that will give you an equivalent stress or adaptation.